# Mapping through two arrays at the same time and passing to a React component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am creating a sorting visualizer that will trace through all the steps of a sorting algorithm.

```
const initializeTrace = (arr) =>
{
    let newState = Array(arr.length).fill(0);

    return [
        {
            array: [...arr],
            states: [...newState],
        }
    ];
};

const addToTrace = (trace, currArr, currStates) =>
{
    let tmpArr = [...currArr];
    let tmpState = [...currStates];

    trace.push(
        {
            array: tmpArr,
            states: tmpState,
        }
    )
};
```

Then I am taking the trace and mapping it to the bars of the sorting visualizer.

```
    return (
        <div onClick={this.onClick} style={{display: 'flex', alignItems: 'flex-end'}}>


            {trace[this.state.traceStep].array.map((el, index) => (
                <Bar key={index} height={el}/>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
```

Example of the first index in the object:

```
{
    "array": [
        15,
        32,
        10,
        11,
        29,
        20,
        7,
        49,
        11,
        21
    ],
    "states": [
        1,
        2,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
    ]
}
```

Right now I am passing the value which will impact the height of the bar. I want to pass the  state as well which will help me dicate what color the bar will be during the trace. Is there a better way to pass this information through to the Bar component. Example, to the first bar I want to pass the height as 15, and the state as 1. Second, 32, 2. Thanks!

Comment: "better" how? Stack Overflow doesn't do well with squishy concepts like "better" or "more elegant" or other opinion-based questions. If the code works, and you're willing to share all of it, and get a review of all of it, you should check [the help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) to see if your question is on topic for [codereview.se], but know they have specific requirements for topicality just like SO.

Comment: I guess better is the wrong word. Right now I can only map through trace.array when I need to map through trace.states at the same time, so I can pass both values to the bar component, so I can do something like <Bar key={index} height={el} state = {state}/> I don't know how to map through both at the same time.

Comment: Just access the other array at the same index (e.g., `trace[this.state.traceStep].states[index]` within your `map`)